# Upgrading path from Lightroom 3 to Lightroom 5

Tags: lightroom-3, lightroom-5

Is it possible to upgrade directly from Lightroom 3 to Lightroom 5 or is it best to go to Lightroom 4 and then to Lightroom 5?

Answer (score 6):

Yes the LR5 installer will migrate a LR3 catalog to LR5, automatically. Better yet, the installer will make a copy of your LR3 catalog, and only migrate the copy, so that your original LR3 catalog is left intact, in case there are problems.

So have no fear, install LR5 (LR3 install will remain).